# Count posts with custom post.variable

Tags: javascript, ejs, hexo

I use Hexo [hexo.io](https://hexo.io), but I guess Jekyll users may know this too as it is similar.

My `custom.post.variable` is `fruit`.
So my `.md` files have:

```
title: food
fruit: apple
```

and

```
title: more food
fruit: banana
```

and

```
title: still more food
fruit: banana
```

and

```
title: try some food
fruit: banana
```

and

```
title: enjoy food
fruit: apple
```

How to count all posts with `fruit: apple`? 
I know that my custom post.variable is not `site` -wide, so that is my problem.
I tried to put my `post.fruit` variable as a function in `site.posts.length` but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Liquid to iterate through the list of posts. Whenever a post has the `fruit` field set to `apple`, then increment a counter.

```
{% assign postCount = 0 %}
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {% if post.fruit == "apple" %}
        {% assign postCount = postCount | plus: 1 %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

The number of posts with 'fruit: apple' is {{postCount}}
```